# How to get the selected list of items from checkboxlist and pass it to the Action in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I am trying to implement a checkboxlist in my MVC application. here I need to get the selected checkboxlist values pass it to @html.ActionLink().
I have searched many sites including Stackoverflow but there is no model binding of database values and getting the selected checkbox values and passing to an action. 
[Eg :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284395/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-view-and-get-the-checked-items-passed-to-the-controller.)

and I tried from this link. [CheckBoxList multiple selections: how to model bind back and get all selections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369533/checkboxlist-multiple-selections-how-to-model-bind-back-and-get-all-selections)

How to get the selected productid from the checkbox list. 
Any examples.. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tags)
{ <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="@item.TagID" @if (item.Selected) { <text>checked="checked"</text> } />@item.Name
  </label>
}
```

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectToRouteResult Edit(IEnumerable<Guid> tag)
    {
        using (var dc = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var existing = dc.Tag
                .Select(i => i.TagID)
                .ToList();

            // remove old
            foreach (var id in existing.Except(tags.EmptyIfNull()))
                dc.Tag.DeleteOnSubmit(dc.Tag.Single(k => k.TagID == id);

            // add new
            foreach (var id in tags.EmptyIfNull().Except(existing))
                dc.Tag.InsertOnSubmit(new Tag() { TagID = id, });

            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```